# Auto-Insert a SQL table when a change is made in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been asked in my work to create a `LOGS Table` in SQL. I was wondering if it's possible to whenever `Table X` suffers an `update` or `insert` it automatically inserts into `Table Y`.

> I'll fill you with some backstory so you can understand why I'm asking this.

I'm developing a Windows Form in VB.NET that has, let's say, some "important data". The problem is that this "important data" is always updated by the user that controls it. Let's say the "important data" consists of creating tickets for FreshDesk.
The way I developed my form was that if `User A` created for the first time a Ticket, I insert the Ticket Title into `Table X` field `Ticket Title`. But, if `User B` changes the `Ticket Title` I automatically update it with the new title. In a way of having historical changes, it's non-existing.

But the thing is, instead of rewriting my code to whenever I updated `Table X` also insert into `Table Y` I wanted SQL to do this, automatically.

Is it possible? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You would use a trigger in SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? I removed these conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: I just noticed that you have tagged your question MySQL and SQL Server. Is it really both or are you spamming tags?

Comment: @Steve: Give it some days time before closing it. Could be a Friday evening question, next checked on Monday morning...

Comment: @The Bamacle: Watch out when you program your first SQL-Trigger: They are set based and not record based! In other words, an UPDATE over 10 records executes the trigger once and not 10 times as you might expect...

Comment: Thanks for everyone who commented! I'll watch tutorials and investigate a little on how to use triggers!

Comment: @Steve: As Christoph said, and thanks again, it was Friday evening, and before I left my work desk I asked this so when I got here Monday I would see if the question had any answers yet. I don't work on Weekends. Maybe I could have had checked this Saturday, I just don't have the habit to do so. Sorry again.

Comment: And for those who wondered why I tagged both `MySQL` and `SQL Server`. At first, I tagged `MySQL` and forgot to remove it. It´s `SQL Server` tho.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the comment! This might be a dummy answer, but does this mean it does not insert the 10 records? I, sometimes, `UPDATE` multiple lines, and I want to `INSERT` those multiple lines. How does it work?

Comment: It depends. If you can write the query in a manner that the 10 records are inserted in a single statement, then it's no problem. If you have to check for every record if it already has an entry or not then you need to check whether inserted contains more than 1 record, and if yes (and only then, in 99% of the cases you have exactly 1 record) you allocate a cursor and loop through each record and insert your record. But why do you need that? If you have a current (>= 2016) SQL-Server, there exists temporal tables if the aim is to audit the data...

Comment: @Christoph: Hmmm, actually yesterday I made my first `Trigger` as you suggested and had exactly the problem you warned me about. Every time `Table X` was updated I inserted in `Table Y` with the old and new value of  `Table X`. When updating multiple lines my old value would always be the same though. I corrected this problem by JOINING the ID of the `inserted` and `deleted` value like this - `FROM inserted CU JOIN deleted de ON de.ID = CU.ID JOIN inserted ins ON ins.ID = CU.ID;`. I'm guessing my `Trigger` is completed by now. Do you think I need anything else? Really thanks btw mate!

Comment: @TheBarnacle: Sounds ambiguous to me. If you are creating a trigger for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` the join would read something like `FROM inserted i LEFT OUTER JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID;`, if you also include the `DELETE` trigger then it would be a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (in both cases assuming the IDs can't be updated). But easiest probably is to create a specific trigger for each operation.

Comment: Alright, I'll check that out! Thanks.